# .on('Input') dynamic updates and additions

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, calculator

I have a set of HTML number inputs with ID's

```
YXS, YSM, YMED
```

I can get the values of each input, add them together, and display the result to #output.

HOWEVER, it only works when entered in order YXS, YSM, YMED

If i remove YSM so its blank, i only get YXS as a value output to #output.

Im trying to work it, so what ever values are entered, they're either added together and displayed, or if only 1 value is entered, then that value is displayed to #output regardless of the order of input.

Ive been scratching my head with it all day, so looking for some help where possible!

Here is my code :

```
$('#YXS').on("input", function() {
    var yxsInput = this.value;
    console.log(yxsInput);
    var Silver = (yxsInput / 100) * 90;               
    var Gold = (yxsInput / 100) * 85;             
    var Plat = (yxsInput / 100) * 80;
    var totalPrice = Number(yxsInput);
    $('#output').text(yxsInput);
    $("#output_Silver").html(Silver.toFixed(2));
    $("#output_Gold").html(Gold.toFixed(2));
    $("#output_Plat").html(Plat.toFixed(2));

    $('#YSM').on("input", function() {
    var ysmInput = this.value;
    console.log(ysmInput);
    var totalPrice = Number(yxsInput)+Number(ysmInput);
    var Silver = (totalPrice / 100) * 90;                 
    var Gold = (totalPrice / 100) * 85;           
    var Plat = (totalPrice / 100) * 80;
    $('#output').text(totalPrice);
    $("#output_Silver").html(Silver.toFixed(2));
    $("#output_Gold").html(Gold.toFixed(2));
    $("#output_Plat").html(Plat.toFixed(2));

    $('#YMED').on("input", function() {
    var ymedInput = this.value;
    console.log(ymedInput);
    var totalPrice = Number(yxsInput)+Number(ysmInput)+Number(ymedInput);
    var Silver = (totalPrice / 100) * 90;                 
    var Gold = (totalPrice / 100) * 85;           
    var Plat = (totalPrice / 100) * 80;
    $('#output').text(totalPrice);
    $("#output_Silver").html(Silver.toFixed(2));
    $("#output_Gold").html(Gold.toFixed(2));
    $("#output_Plat").html(Plat.toFixed(2));
    });
});
```

I have tried getting the inputs first

```
$('#YXS').on("input", function() {
    var yxsInput = this.value;
    console.log(yxsInput);

    $('#YSM').on("input", function() {
    var ysmInput = this.value;
    console.log(ysmInput);

    $('#YMED').on("input", function() {
    var ymedInput = this.value;
    console.log(ymedInput);
```

Which didnt work out either and console would tell me that yxsInput (for example) is not defined.

Hope ive explained well enough what my end goal is!

Many thanks,

Comment: Java != JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your `input` event handlers are nested. So YSM and YMED trigger if only YXS is triggered.

Actually you don't need to have a separate handler for each input. See the snippet below:

```js
$('#YXS, #YSM, #YMED').on("input", function() {
        var totalPrice = 0;
        $('#YXS, #YSM, #YMED').each(function(i, e) {totalPrice += ~~e.value});
        var Silver = totalPrice * 0.9;                 
        var Gold = totalPrice * 0.85;           
        var Plat = totalPrice * 0.8;
        $('#output').text(totalPrice);
        $("#output_Silver").html(Silver.toFixed(2));
        $("#output_Gold").html(Gold.toFixed(2));
        $("#output_Plat").html(Plat.toFixed(2));
    });
```

```css
label, h3 {display:flex;
justify-content:space-between;
width:14rem; margin:1rem 0; padding:0}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label>YXS: <input id="YXS"></label>
<label>YSM: <input id="YSM"></label>
<label>YMED: <input id="YMED"></label>

<h3>Silver: <span id="output_Silver">0.00</span></h3>
<h3>Gold: <span id="output_Gold">0.00</span></h3>
<h3>Plat: <span id="output_Plat">0.00</span></h3>
<h3>Total: <span id="output">0</span></h3>
```

Comment: Thankyou so much for the reply. I did try that as well, but what happens is, if i fill on YMED only, i get NOTHING out to #output, i think due to this : 

var totalPrice = Number(yxsInput)+Number(ysmInput)+Number(ymedInput);

Also, if i un-nest them, if i fill in #YXS then move onto the next, #output doesnt update with the other values, so closing that 1st function (#XYS) stops the other functions/inputs working

Comment: @EdwardHill, that's another problem. Please gimme some time. I'll make a snippet for you.

Comment: You're an angel! :)

Comment: AWESOME! Thankyou, so new problem! 

I ran your code, and when i input 5 into YXS the value that goes to #output is actually 7, what ever goes in YXS, 2 gets added to it!

Also, i have various other inputs on the same form, is it possible i can declare which ID's to use the inputs from?

Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: @EdwardHill, I've updated my answer again to restrict the calculation to #YXS, #YSM, #YMED only.