# .on('Input') dynamic updates and additions part 2

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

please see [this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48725093/oninput-dynamic-updates-and-additions) for context...

The script has the function of adding various "clones" of the original inputs ID's for example :

```
#YXS
```

Would be come

```
#YXS2
```

This happens via this code from an external js file

```
// Increment input ID
                clone.find(':input').attr('id', function(i, val) {
                    return val + count;
                });
```

So in the original code :

```
$('#YXS, #YSM, #YMED, #YLRG, #YXLRG, #SM, #MED, #LRG, #XL, #XXL, #XXXL, #XXXXL').on("input", function() {
```

Ive tried adding "#YXS2" to the list, but its not working out as intended.

For more context here is the form [here, but not 100% this is just example of its appearance](http://axelradco.com/tset/). So you can see when you click the "+" icon to add a garment, a new instance of that form appears.

Hopefully my explanation isnt TOO sketchy! Any help is awesome help! Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have no idea what your question is, but please don't use incremental `id` attributes like that. They are an anti-pattern as they become a pain to maintain very quickly, and make the code to create the elements needlessly complex. I'd suggest using a common class on the elements instead. If you need to relate them to each other, use DOM traversal

Comment: Hi Rory, thanks for the message! :) 

Ive updated the file to use classes rather than ID's but, on the 2nd "form input" its failing to register, if you go to this link : http://axelradco.com/tset/ you can see that in the "Garment" section there is a + button, which adds a new instance of the Garment form. Each of the size inputs has a class, but the form only recognises the 1st instance, NOT the 2nd (when added)